# Setting up a GUI application on Linux for a Touch Display, while disallowing OS access

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, user-interface

I am working in an industrial setting, where I would like to have a GUI application on a touch display, running under Ubuntu 22.04. I want users to interact with that GUI without having total access to the system. I am wondering, how this is typically handled.

The system runs a python script, which operates a machine. For manual operators working in the facility, the touch display should give some functionality to start and stop the system, adapt config, etc. What I do not want to allow is for operators to have full access to the operation system, as well as my python programs. My program includes a FastAPI, so external programs could communicate with my Python program.

Hence, I would like to figure out, how to have such interactive GUIs. I know that many machine manufacturers have such solutions, but they commonly don't use a "normal" PC.

I have done some search, but somehow struggle to find the right words to explain, what I need. I assume there is technical nomenclature for this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for "kiosk" mode. There are probably other similar terms as well.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].